# Can't search unanswered questions with multiple tags

Tags: support, tags, unanswered-questions

I've searched for this specific answer with no luck.
I want to be able to filter **unanswered** questions with [tag1] **AND** [tag2], but it doesn't seem to work for unanswered.

When I use a link like this: https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/sql+oracle

Even though it has a "+", it still treats it as an OR.
I want unanswered questions containing both tags. Is this possible? Unclear if this is a possible bug/feature/ or user error.

Comment: Have you tried: "isanswered:false [tag1] [tag2]"?

Comment: @John - that looked good at first, but when I scrolled down a page or two, I'm still seeing some answered ones. I typed this into the search bar:  [sql] [oracle] isanswered:false as well as, isanswered:false [sql] [oracle] in case order counts

Comment: You are right in the sense that "isanswered:false" will show answers with a score<=0. Perhaps try "answers:0" along with the desired tags. Like this: "answers:0 [tag1] [tag2]".

Comment: "unanswered" has an odd definition... it means questions with no upvoted or accepted answers, not zero answers.

Comment: answers:0 is close enough, thanks John! isanswered:false seems to allow accepted answers, if they aren't upvoted, which is unexpected. I say "close enough" because I would prefer questions with unaccepted answers too, since that's how "https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered" normally works.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344924/bug-in-unanswered-tag-search

Comment: Do you want http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/sql+oracle?tab=noanswers ?

Comment: @Pandya that doesn't include oracle AND sql tags for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm... It is not working as expected. Btw, following are workarounds to get expected result:

1. **Forcing `and`**

   https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/sql+and+oracle
2. Using /questions instead

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+sql?sort=unanswered

Using Advance Search: `isanswered:0 [sql] [oracle]` for no positively scored answers & `answers:0 [sql] [oracle]` for no answer at all.

Comment: It doesn't look like isanswered:0 is working correctly, but the other options work well.